# python regex replace returns an extra \n

Tags: python, file, search, replace

I am trying to replace some text in a file with python 2.6

However, it returns an extra newline here is my code:

```
for line in fileinput.input('/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini', inplace=True):
   replace = re.sub(r'(post_max_size =).[0-9]+(M)', r'\1 64\2', line)
   print replace
```

Input:

```
post_max_size = 6M
sdfsdfsd
post_max_size = 4M
sdfsdf
post_max_size = 164M
dfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

output:

```
post_max_size = 64M

sdfsdfsd

post_max_size = 64M

sdfsdf

post_max_size = 64M

dfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: 
`print replace,` instead.  The trailing comma suppresses the newline (but adds a trailing space).  For complete control use the print function from `__future__` instead.

Comment: Thanks cdarke. Its just works fine. However, I haven't understand the `_future_`. Will you please explain it? sorry that I am so new to python.

Comment: @Rabit;  if you are new to Python then don't worry too much about the new `print` function.  It is the default on Python 3, from (I think) Python 2.6 you can use it if you: `from __future__ import print_function`.  It is easier to use and gives more control, but probably better left until you move to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The extra output you are seing is from `print`, if you write the file back out, you should not see the extra line breaks.

Try it with this: `print replace,`

This is a minor point, but you should also pick a different name, as `replace` is the name for a method in the standard library for strings.

Comment: I have just tried it out and found the file returns simply blank. However thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: What do you mean 'returns simply blank'?

Comment: Perhaps you are not writing the correct string out. You should create a new question (after you [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to this one).

Answer (score 0):

your regex is fine. `print` adds newline. use `write` instead.